# Execute two onsubmit functions; second function executes only if first function is true

Tags: javascript, function, execute, onsubmit

I have an email form validation script. If this first function returns true (no errors in email field), then the second function will execute, which is simply a url redirect. Can someone combine these two functions, so that all I need to put in the the form is something like, `onsubmit="return checkForm();"`

Comment: Can we see your code? Are there any hidden issues that make it non-trivial in your case?

Comment: Nothing plus nothing is… well, nothing. Show me the code!

Answer (score 2):

Call the second function from within the first:

```
function checkForm()
{
    // Your validation logic here
    if (valid)
        doRedirect();
}
```